# Katalon Studio - Find all inputs with specific type and click them

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

In Katalon Studio, I have a form that has a dynamic number of checkboxes.
I need to click on all checkboxes.

I tried the below, but it only clicks on the first checkbox:

```
TestObject agreement = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'input[type="checkbox"]')

for (def index : (0..0)) {
    WebUI.click(agreement)  
}
```

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: What is with that for-loop?

Comment: Have you given up on this question?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly with a single `TestObject`.

You need `WebElement`s for the checkboxes. Don't worry: you can convert them back into `TestObject`s, so you can still use those built-in `WebUI` keywords on them...

Here, try this:

```
DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
  .findElements(By.css("input[type = 'checkbox']"))
  .collect { WebElement checkboxEl -> return WebUI.convertWebElementToTestObject(checkboxEl); }
  .each { TestObject checkbox ->
    WebUI.scrollToElement(checkbox, 2);
    WebUI.click(checkbox);
  }
```